# Add custom variables in magento 2 to use in REST API

Tags: rest, api, magento2

I am using some data in my web site like social links, contact address, contact phone, slider banners, I can use them as html in blocks or contact pages. But I am facing a problem, How to call them as REST API. I Already uses Magento2 API:

```
/V1/cmsBlock/:blockId 
/V1/cmsPage/:pageId
```

But the respobse is html and it is so bad. any help?

Comment: I think if you don't want to get HTML from that you will have to write a custom module that allows you to input the fields you need as plain text organized in a way that you can use them as an API response.
If the data you are trying to get is already available separately (like the phone number) you might just need to create an extension that adds the api endpoint you need.

Comment: can you help more? I am new in magento 2

Comment: What data are you trying to fetch from API exactly?

Comment: External data which have no configs in backend like, slider banners, social links, contact numbers and address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the data like social links, contact numbers etc I suggest you to add this as text in the configuration, to do so you can create a module that has the following structure:

`app/code/Jsparo/Customapi/registration.php`

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Jsparo_Customapi',
    __DIR__
);
```

`app/code/Jsparo/Customapi/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Jsparo_Customapi" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

`app/code/Jsparo/Customapi/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
    <tab id="jsparo" translate="label" sortOrder="1100">
        <label>Jsparo</label>
    </tab>
    <section id="jsparo_social" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
        <label>Social</label>
        <tab>jsparo</tab>
        <resource>Jsparo_Social::config</resource>
        <group id="facebook" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
            <label>Facebook</label>
            <field id="url" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Facebook Url</label>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
</system>
</config>
```

`app/code/Jsparo/Customapi/etc/webapi.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/jsparo/facebook" method="GET">
        <service class="Jsparo\Customapi\Api\FacebookInterface" method="getUrl"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

`app/code/Jsparo/Customapi/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Jsparo\Customapi\Api\FacebookInterface" type="Jsparo\Customapi\Model\Facebook"/>
</config>
```

`app/code/Jsparo/Customapi/Api/FacebookInterface.php`

```
<?php
namespace Jsparo\Customapi\Api;
interface FacebookInterface {
    /**
     * @return string $url
     */
    public function getUrl();
}
```

`app/code/Jsparo/Customapi/Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php
namespace Jsparo\Customapi\Helper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
class Data extends AbstractHelper {

    const prefix = 'jsparo_social/';
    private function moduleConfig($key) {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::prefix . $key);
    }

    public function getFacebookUrl() {
        return $this->moduleConfig('facebook/url');
    }
}
```

`app/code/Jsparo/Customapi/Model/Facebook.php`

```
<?php
namespace Jsparo\Customapi\Model;
use Jsparo\Customapi\Helper\Data;
class Facebook implements FacebookInterface {

    private $helper;

    public function __construct(
        Data $helper
    ) {
        $this->helper = $helper;
    }

    public function getUrl() {
        return $this->helper->getFacebookUrl();
    }
}
```

You might have to do some adjustments and add all the fields / api endpoints that you need to it.

You can add also Caching to your API by using the `Magento\Framework\App\CacheInterface` to avoid having to perform certain computations.

Notice that I created the endpoint with the `anonymous` role, so that it is not protected.

EDIT: I created a [github repository](https://github.com/oirad/Jsparo_Customapi) where you can see the full source and edited the couple typos that were above. I assume that this module source code gets added in `app/code/Jsparo/Customapi`.

Comment: Thank you. But I got this error in backend->stores->configuration `"Notice: Undefined index: id in /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Magento/Config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php on line 59";i:1;s:4888:"#0 /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Magento/Config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php(59): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined index...', '/var/www/html/m...', 59, Array)
`

Comment: What version of magento 2 are you using?

Comment: I am using magento V 2.1.4

Comment: I edited my answer to fix the typos and created a github repo where you can have a look at the full code easier.

Comment: Hi bro, Thank you very much. If I can ask, what is the best steps and tutorials to learn magento 2?

Comment: They had some free online courses in the past months, not sure if those are still available (on the official magento website). But I believe that the best way to learn is to check how these things have been implemented in the core by the magento team and read the documentation.

Comment: Sorry, It is not or topic, but can you have a look on this question: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43448327/invalid-request-field-order-avsdetails-billtofirstname-was-not-in-charset-is`